# INotificationConfiguration does not contain a definition for 'Notifiers'

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

Im following the aspboilerplate documentation to add a custom email notified as per the example on this page:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System#multiple-notifiers

The document states the following:

> Add it in the PreInitialize method of your module:
>
> `Configuration.Notifications.Notifiers.Add<EmailRealTimeNotifier>();`

However i get the following error:

> INotificationConfiguration does not contain a definition for
>   'Notifiers'

Ive tried adding what i think are the obvious using statements but thing has worked

The only extension methods that i can see are for Providers and Distributors which error if i attempt to inject the EmailRealTimeNotifier i created.

Can someone help with an explanation or workarround please.

Thanks in  advance

Comment: Which version of ABP are you on?

Comment: Version 4.3.0 according to the nuget packages. It's the same version across all the abp packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to ABP v4.4+ to use multiple notifiers.

- v4.4 was released in March.
- v4.6 (the latest version) was released in May.

Comment: Restart your VS and/or computer.